# how to get raw html string with jQuery .get()

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, get

I need to get raw html with `<div>` tags and everything, and put it in a variable string.

So if I have a separate file test.html

```
<div>
<div><img src="images/htc_hero_wallpaper_01.jpg" width="20%" height="20%" alt="" /></div>
WORKS!!!
</div>
```

I need the jQuery command

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  success: function(){

 var htmlraw = ?????
 alert(htmlraw)  /// should print the raw test.html
  }
});
```

to print

```
<div>
<div><img src="images/htc_hero_wallpaper_01.jpg" width="20%" height="20%" alt="" /></div>
WORKS!!!
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is probably way too late, but the correct way to do this is by setting the [fourth parameter to $.get (the `dataType`)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to "text":

```
$.get("test.html", null, function(html) {
    console.log(html);
}, "text");
```

Otherwise, it will auto-detect that the response is HTML and parse it for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.get({
  url: "test.html",
  success: function(data){

 var htmlraw = data;
 //alert(htmlraw)  /// should print the raw test.html
 $("#someDiv").html(htmlraw);
  }
});
```

Comment: [object XMLdocument] is the output

Comment: have you hosted on any server locally? atleast apache/IIS?

Comment: Probably the problem lies somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at .html() from jQuery http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the html of a specific element in your file, you can find the element and append it to a new element. This way, you will be able to get the raw html string with `.html()`

```
$.get("test.html", function(data)
{
    var specificEl = $(data).find('#specific-element');
    var html = $(document.createElement('div')).append(specificEl).html();

    console.log(html);
});
```